# TMPro Unnasigned on play, problem identified, not sure how to solve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I'm writing this code to control generated planets. The code is attached to a prefab that is randomly generated. The prefab has multiple UI texts. I'm trying to access each one individually in reference to the prefab... not just through inspect. When I just drag it in inspector it doesn't carry over for each clone. How can I specify a specific UI text in my prefab so that it will carry over for clones?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class planetManagerV1 : MonoBehaviour
{
        public Texture2D[] planet_textures;
        public int max_nuetral_hp;
        private int starting_nuetral_hp;
        public TextMeshProUGUI dyamicHPtxt;
        public TextMeshProUGUI HPtxt;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {   
        //Choose Random texture
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = planet_textures[Random.Range(0, planet_textures.Length)];
        //Set Nuetral Planet Tag
        dynamicHPtxt = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        HPtxt = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        starting_nuetral_hp = Random.Range(1, max_nuetral_hp);
        //Set Texts
        dynamicHPtxt.text = starting_nuetral_hp.ToString();
        HPtxt.text = "uh oh";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Start` you have

```
dynamicHPtxt = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
HPtxt = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

This might

- a) in case there is no such a component on the **same** GameObject as this script overwrite the references with `null` and therefore they are not assigned in clones
- b) Both calls actually return exactly the same reference: The first encountered TMP component **on the same GameObject as this script** or `null` if none was found.

If as you say you already setup and reference both things correctly in the prefab then get completely rid of these two `GetComponent` calls!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried updating your prefab? You should be able to link them through the inspector and then click overrides and apply all (upper right corner of the inspector).